# The sigma algebra of Borel sets in complex numbers

Tags: measure-theory

Let us focus on the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

We denote $O$, by the set of all open balls centered at zero. Let $\sigma$ be the sigma algebra generated by $O$.

Is $\sigma$ just the sigma algebra of Borel sets in $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not. If $E\in\sigma$ then $E$ is rotation-invariant (that is, $e^{it}E:=\{e^{it}z:z\in E\}=E$). In fact $\sigma$ is precisely the set of all rotation-invariant Borel sets.